# How to split a input to each character?

Tags: python

Suppose I get input as `apple`, how can I split it in list of each character like `['a','p','p','l','e']`?

I tried `[i for i in input().split('')]`,

but it outputs error: `ValueError: empty separator`.

Comment: Just do `list('apple')`.

Comment: @coluloci Once you have found an answer which works for you, please click the tick next to that answer to accept it. This lets other people with your problem know which solution works for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `list('apple')`.

This will split the string `'apple'` into individual characters and place them inside a `list`.

**Output:**

```
['a','p','p','l','e']
```